# How to interpolate (or regrid) large matrix in python?

Tags: python, interpolation

How can I interpolate large matrix in python?

I want to interpolate a 5685 x 5567 matrix.

It is a satellite dataset with orthographic projection.

So longitude and latitude matrix also have a same shape with dataset (5685 x 5567)

I want to make it lower resolution dataset with 1-D longitude and latitude like mercator projection.

So I tried it by

```
import fnmatch
import glob
import os

import numpy as np
import h5py
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from scipy import interpolate

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'COMS*L2A*'):
        chlfn=file
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'*SST.nc'):
        sstfn=file
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'daylength.nc'):
        dlfn=file
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'*OC.nc'):
        ocfn=file
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'COMS*LON*.he5'):
        glonfn=file
    elif fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'COMS*LAT*.he5'):
        glatfn=file

sstnc = Dataset(glob.glob(sstfn)[0])
ocnc = Dataset(glob.glob(ocfn)[0])
dlnc = Dataset(glob.glob(dlfn)[0])
chlh5 = h5py.File(chlfn,'r')
glonh5=h5py.File(glonfn,'r')
glath5=h5py.File(glatfn,'r')

daynum = int(glob.glob(sstfn)[0][5:8])

modis_lon = sstnc.variables['lon'][:]
modis_lat = sstnc.variables['lat'][:]

goci_lon=glonh5['/HDFEOS/GRIDS/Image Data/Data Fields/Longitude Image Pixel Values']
goci_lat=glath5['/HDFEOS/GRIDS/Image Data/Data Fields/Latitude Image Pixel Values']

sst = sstnc.variables['sst'][:]
kd = ocnc.variables['Kd_490'][:]
par = ocnc.variables['par'][:]
dl = dlnc.variables['Daylength'][daynum - 1, :, :]
chl=chlh5['HDFEOS/GRIDS/Image Data/Data Fields/CHL Image Pixel Values']

chl_masked=np.ma.masked_less(chl[:],0)

flags_sst = sstnc.variables['flags_sst'][:]
flags_oc = ocnc.variables['l2_flags'][:]

setflags_oc = [1, 2, 8, 512, 4096, 16384, 32768, 16777216, 1073741824]
setflags_sst = [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 4096, 8192, 16384, -32768]

modis_lon2d, modis_lat2d = np.meshgrid(modis_lon, modis_lat)

interp2=interpolate.interp2d(goci_lon,goci_lat,chl)

chl_int=interp2(modis_lon2d,modis_lat2d)
```

modis_lon and modis_lat is 1-D array (2031 x 1 and 3006 x 1, respectively)

goci_lon and goci_lat is 2-D array (5685 x 5567)

But it shows error message "OverflowError: Too many data points to interpolate".

Using griddata also did not working.

Comment: code looks like it is not proper. there is no function interpolate i can find of in scipy. and interp2 is not a function either but i assume it is interp2d. but still you cannot call it like that with your imports. can you share your code properly so we can reproduce the error?

Comment: I attached my code in text body.